# Rails: Date select helper without dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

is there an easy way in ruby on rails to enter a date/time without dropdowns. I know there is the datetime_select helper method, but this just produces drop down menues which are not really nice to use when entering multiple dates.

I pretty much just want a number field for each d/m/y so you can just tab through. I tried this an it works nicely, but I have to put the dates back together in the controller with date_civil which gets a bit annoying because I have about 10 dates in one form...

**edit:**

in the view:

```
            <td> <%= number_field_tag "fill_count_d", nil, :placeholder =>"DD", :size => 1 %>-
                 <%= number_field_tag "fill_count_m",  nil, :placeholder =>"MM", :size => 1 %>-
                 <%= number_field_tag "fill_count_y",  nil, :placeholder =>"YYYY", :size => 2%>    
                 <%= number_field_tag "fill_count_h",  nil, :placeholder =>"hh", :size => 1 %> : 
                 <%= number_field_tag "fill_count_min",  nil, :placeholder =>"mm", :size => 1%> </td>
```

int the controller:

```
@m.fill_count =    DateTime.civil(params[:fill_count_y].to_i,
                                  params[:fill_count_m].to_i,
                                  params[:fill_count_d].to_i,
                                  params[:fill_count_h].to_i,
                                  params[:fill_count_min].to_i)
```

Comment: Can you post what you already have? Maybe it is adaptable to a more flexible way ;)

Answer (score 0):

What would you say for javascript and jquery ?

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months

or

http://keith-wood.name/dateEntry.html

Comment: unfortunately on this project I'm not allowed to use JS